# Require HTML to be submitted to ASHX Handler

Tags: c#, html, ajax, ashx

My requirement is that I need to submit the entire(HTML) content of the page to a ashx handler, for further processing within it.  I actually need to get an html stream of the content for PDF conversion.

I would not be able to use a WebRequest for the page from within my C# code as there are a number of Async renderings happening after the first time the page loads. I'm using a static page with Angular as backbone.

Is there some secure way to this  or is there some better approach to to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "Is there some secure way?" What security problems are you concerned about?

Comment: HTML tampering is my concern when the content is sent.

Comment: Well, the user can always manipulate HTML on their computer prior to submitting it. You really can't prevent that. Instead, you can generate the PDF entirely on the server side, and forget about involving the client side. And while you're at it, you should avoid using HTML to generate the PDF. Instead, directly manipulate the PDF using whatever library you choose.

Comment: Hi The issue was with my HTML. There were some display:none tags within it so the content wasnt getting rendered. The web request did send HTML back.Closing the thread